# How to setAttribute for element from radiobutton without submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many buttons. If I click by one of them calls this function:

```
function addOptions(id)
{
  var button = document.getElementById(id); //clicked button
  radioDiv = document.querySelector("div.radioDiv");
  radioDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
  var raz = document.getElementsByName('status'); //get radioButtons
  $(".radioDiv").ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=status]').change(function(){

         /*Here I'm trying to set attribute to only one button but 
           here the problem: when I click a few buttons (example: 1st then 2nd, then 3rd) 
           and on 3rd button I choice the "radioButton" this code is set Attribute for 
           all of them (3) */

                button.setAttribute("status", this.value);  
            });
          });
        }
```

[image]

Here index.html. RadioDiv is hidden by default

```
   <div class="layer1">
    <div class="radioDiv">
      <input type="radio" value="sale" name="status">111
      <input type="radio" value="inverted" name="status">222
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="layer2"></div>
```

So, I need to set Attribute for button from value of RadioButton.

Comment: Could you post complete code? `html` for buttons too?

Comment: buttons code is generating dynamically. Here is complete html: `button class="class1" id="1.1" onclick="addOptions('1.1') `

Comment: @Teemu it works the same without `$(".radioDiv").ready(function() {...})` just `$('input[type=radio][name=status]').change(function(){..}`

Comment: @ZhiV you are binding change event on each click.....

Comment: @ZhiV why you on button click you want to bind a change event in which the status of that button is updated? usecase?

Comment: Do you need something like https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/243/

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki nope, only one radioDiv for many buttons. + need set checked value on radioButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a global variable at the beginning of your js file.

```
var lastButton;
function addOptions(id) {
  $(".radioDiv input[type=radio][name=status]").prop("checked", false);
  lastButton = document.getElementById(id); //last clicked button
  var status = lastButton.getAttribute("status");
  $(".radioDiv input[type=radio][name=status][value='" + status +"']").prop("checked", true);
  $(".radioDiv").prop("visible", true);
  $('input[type=radio][name=status]').click(function(){
    lastButton.setAttribute("status", this.value);
  });
}
```

Comment: And how to set checked value in radioDiv? For example: we set value for 1st button, then click on 2nd button and we see that radioButton didn't change. Moreover when we get back on 1st button we see that radioButton can be wrong (if on previous button we changed it)

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure of what you are trying to achieve (you should call things by their names because you seem to be mixing up value and status, buttons and radioboxes), if you use the right words and explain clearly what you want to achieve I think I can help you.

Comment: see updated answer, now, clicking on the big blue buttons resets the radio boxes

Comment: Oh ok I understand now what you want to do. Please wait I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Where you have the following markup:

```
<div id="status" class="radioDiv">
  <input type="radio" value="sale" name="status">111
  <input type="radio" value="inverted" name="status">222
</div>
```

You can grab both radio buttons as a *node list* with:

```
var statusRadioButtons = document.getElementById('status').getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Then each button is an item in the *node list*:

- `statusRadioButtons[0]`
- `statusRadioButtons[1]`